# how to display the data per hour in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to display the data per hour?

for example:

```
data = [
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:20:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 12:30:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 11:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 07:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample'
        'date' : '2020-02-18 01:50:01'
    }
]
```

what I want to do here is display the data from hour.
example
14:00:00 - 13:00:00

```
const sample = data.filter((data) => { return data.date });

console.log(sample);
```

Comment: Per hour of any given date? Or per hour and per date? Any attempts so far?

Comment: the date is given. then it will filter hour ago

Comment: Also: do you consider `12:70:01` to be between `13:00:00` and `14:00:00`?

Comment: sorry for the typo error

Comment: from the latest to hour ago

Comment: example 13:50:01 to 12:50:01

Comment: I understand what you need, but the fact of the matter remains that Stack Overflow expects you to at least make an attempt at doing it yourself. Can't just expect someone to do your job for you...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I try to filter the data.

Comment: OK, is the array always sorted like this? I.e. the most recent first and then the rest of the items in descending order?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes the array is sorted by descending

Answer (score 2):

Live demo: https://runkit.com/embed/21avr87izvdn

[image]

```
    const data = [
    {
        'name' : 'sample',
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample',
        'date' : '2020-02-18 13:20:01',
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample',
        'date' : '2020-02-18 12:70:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample',
        'date' : '2020-02-18 11:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample',
        'date' : '2020-02-18 07:50:01'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'sample',
        'date' : '2020-02-18 01:50:01'
    }
];

const getTime = date => date.split(' ')[1]; 

const filterByRange = (start, end) => 
      data.filter(item =>  getTime(item.date) > start &&
                           getTime(item.date) < end);

filterByRange('13:00', '14:00');
```

Comment: Little bit dangerous, no? Passing non-ISO date strings to the `Date` constructor?

Comment: That took care of that, but you're still not answering OP's question.

Comment: You're getting closer :) OP seems to want to have the ones between the timestamp of the most recent one and one hour before that, but +1 for the effort so far.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks for the upvote. Refactored again to make it more generic and I thought this will be even closer to call filterByRange() in a loop, :)